# I can't downcast an NSDictionary, CFDictionaryRef, nor an NSMutableDictionary, to SecItemAdd()

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I don't understand Keychain that well. As far as I know you want to send a `CFDictionaryRef` to `SecItemAdd()` to store the attributes in applications' keychain. I'm probably not understanding unwrapping or something. I feel like the answer is obvious but this is my first experience with something so low-level, so please be patient with me. :)

Here's my Swift:

```
var keychainDictionary : NSMutableDictionary? = NSMutableDictionary()
var username = "Arcrammer"
var password = "somePassword"
var site = "http://www.hausofalexander.tk/"

// Item class
keychainDictionary![(kSecClass as String)] = kSecClassInternetPassword

// Attributes
keychainDictionary![(kSecAttrAccount as String)] = username
keychainDictionary![(kSecAttrService as String)] = "Haus"
keychainDictionary![(kSecAttrAccessible as String)] = kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly as CFTypeRef)
keychainDictionary![(kSecMatchCaseInsensitive as String)] = (kCFBooleanTrue asCFTypeRef)
keychainDictionary![(kSecReturnData as String)] = (kCFBooleanTrue as CFTypeRef)

// Completely mutable NSDictionary from the NSMutableDictionary
var result : OSStatus?
SecItemAdd(keychainDictionary!, result)
```

I've created an empty and optional `NSMutableDictionary()` to hold the Keychain dictionary attributes and values. Next, I add add some `kSecAttr-` values to the dictionary as keys. I'm also casting them as `String` because the compiler throws the error `LoginViewController.swift:112:37: Type 'CFStringRef' does not conform to protocol 'NSCopying'` if I try to  them as `CFTypeRef` or I don't try to cast them at all. Of course, `String` does conform to the `NSCopying` protocol. I don't know if this has an effect on the attribute value, but it definitely dismisses the error.

After that I continue to pass information as the `String` data type. From what I've gathered (which isn't much, tbh) `CFTypeRef` is an enumeration and the data returned by something like `kCFBooleanTrue` will return the type value from that enumeration which would be something like `CFBoolean`, `CFDictionary`, or basically what `AnyObject` or `id` would be to Foundation.

After that I proceed to create an empty variable named `result` with the type `OSStatus`. This variable will hold the result of the `AddSecItem()` function following on line 118.

However, I'm given the following error:
`swift:118:17: Cannot convert the expression's type '(@lvalue NSMutableDictionary, @lvalue OSStatus?)' to type 'CFDictionary!'`

I have no idea what this means and I can't figure it out. What in the world am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would help if you include the signature of `SecItemAdd`

Comment: The signature? What is the signature? Are you referring to my code signing id?

Comment: No. It's just how the function is declared with parameters. Body is not needed.

Comment: Haven't I added that? It's line 118 `118 SecItemAdd(keychainDictionary!, result)
` :/

Comment: No. Where did you declare it? `func SecItemAdd (???)`

Comment: I haven't declared that function myself. I thought that was part of UIKit or Foundation. Here's the reference for the method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemAdd

Edit: It's part of Security.

Comment: Well, not everybody knows everything in Apple's libraries, but from that signature it's easy to see that you need to supply a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<AnyObject>?>` and it returns an `OSStatus`.

Comment: How in the world do I find out how to do that? I've never even seen syntax like that.

Edit: I changed 118 `SecItemAdd(keychainDictionary!, UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<result>?>)` and I'm given the error `LoginViewController.swift:118:80: 'result' is not a type`

Comment: I'd say: RTFM :-/ Google for `UnsafeMutablePoiter Swift` to find the basics. If you need `SecItemAdd` you need to supply the right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the parameter supply for `SecItemAdd` but you need more something like

```
var idontknow = UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<AnyObject>?>()
result = SecItemAdd(keychainDictionary!, idontknow)
```

Try to find out from the docu what `idontknow` exactly is.